# 103666 vb.net for saving image in image folder and in database after scanning

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project related to saving an image captured from a scannner in a folder and in the database. The scan performs ok but when I save the image on disk and the path in the database I get the following error

> DATABASE --tablename--image column--(File_Name,varchar50,null=true),(Image,nvarchar(Max),null=true)

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Button14_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button14.Click
    ''SCAN THE IMAGE AND SAVE TO PROJECT FOLDER AND IN DATABASE (AS BLOB)
    If True Then
        ' Scanner selected?
        Dim device = TryCast(Devices.SelectedItem, Scanner)
        If device Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a device.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            Return
        End If

        ' Scan
        Dim image = device.Scan()

        'Save the image

        'Dim path = "image/"
        'If File.Exists(path) Then
        '    File.Delete(path)
        'End If
        'image.SaveFile(TextBox1.Text, "image/")
        'image.save()


    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Check if the size of path is exceeding 50 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems with your table design:

1) The file name, at 50 characters, is most likely not long enough, especially if you include the path.

2) Storing the image data in an nvarchar will most likely cause numerous issues. You would be much better off using varbinary. [Here is a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158.aspx) to some information from Microsoft.

Comment: your answer is good but i want to know that how i save image in image folder and its path in database by using button click event